# Reverse String - ArrayOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

I want to change String "Hello World" to "World hello". Here's my code:

```
    class StringTest
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            String str= "Hello World";
            String wordcount[]=str.split(" ");
            int count= wordcount.length;
            System.out.println(count);
            for(int i=count;i>0;i--)
            {
                System.out.print(wordcount[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Getting error `ArrayOutOfBoundException`. Please help.

Comment: Your qustion is a) a duplicate, or b) off-topic because it's a "fix my code" question.

Comment: you can use StringBuilder#reverse

Comment: @Tichodroma then why don't you vote for close

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I did. Strange, the comment is deleted?!

Comment: @Tichodroma because it is not a valid reason.

Answer (score 3):

There is no index matched with `count`.

starting index of array is 0th index. So if your array has length `5` it has index from `0` to `4`

Change

```
  for(int i=count;i>0;i--){ // there is no index in array for count
     // and this for loop not consider 0th index
     System.out.print(wordcount[i]);
  }
```

to

```
  for(int i=count-1;i>-1;i--){ //now loop starts from count-1 and consider 0index
            System.out.print(wordcount[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero-based in Java. You should do:

```
for(int i=count-1;i>0;i--)
                ↑
```

If you have an array of size `N`, the indexes are in range `[0, N-1]`:

```
"I love to lie down and pretend I'm a carrot"
 ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓                                ↓
 0123456789...                             42
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
  String str= "Hello World";
            String wordcount[]=str.split(" ");
            int count= wordcount.length;
            System.out.println(count);
            for(int i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                System.out.print(wordcount[i]);
            }
```